# brew install tree failed with ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, tree, homebrew

I was installing tree in my mac

MacBookPro
OS X Yosemite v 10.10.3

When I hit the command,

> $ brew install tree
>   ==> Downloading http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/src/tree-1.7.0.tgz Already
>   downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tree-1.7.0.tgz
>   ==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/tree/1.7.0 MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/tree/1.7.0/share/man/man1 CC=clang
>   CFLAGS=-fomit-frame-pointer LDFLAGS= OBJS=tree.o unix.o html.o xml.o
>   hash.o co   "start", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [tree] Error 1
>
> READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
>
> These open issues may also help: brew-deps: improved --tree formatting
>   (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/40018)

sounds like something is not inline with the 64 bit architecture.

Can somebody help me on this ??

Comment: Can you share the output of `brew gist-logs tree` please?

Comment: Hi @TimSmith, I tried to create a gist-log,  but the url created do not work on the https://gistlog.co/ :)